# Where is ClaimTypes.IdentityProvider?

Tags: wif, .net-4.5, claims-based-identity, acs

Using .Net 4.5 RC and Azure Access Control Service, the primary claims I am interested in are the IdentityProvider and the NameIdentifier.

System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes contains constants for well-known claims, and it has ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, but it appears to be missing ClaimTypes.IdentityProvider.

I was really surprised not to find it there.  Of course, I can just use the string representation "http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider" in one of my own constants, but given Microsoft's push towards the cloud, I would expect to find it in with the standard ClaimTypes.

Is this is just oversight?  Is there a good reason for it's absence? Is it in some other namespace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would venture that the IdentityProvider claim is not part of the standard set of WIF claim types because the IdentityProvider is already a required field present in the issued security token, separate from the set of claims.

ACS on the other hand sits as a federation provider between the relying party application and  the 3rd party identity provider. Note that ACS does not use the [ActAs or OnBehalfOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748487.aspx) mechanisms, but the RP might like to know what IP the user is coming from so ACS issues the IdentityProvider claim for this purpose.